# Cannot recognize input near 'user' 'STRUCT' '<' in column name or primary key or foreign key in hive

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

I am trying to perform twitter analysis using hive but I am getting error as mentioned above. I already add the jar file as shown below and got no error in that, but while creating the external table I get the error as shown below:

> FAILED: ParseException line 9:2 cannot recognize input near 'user'
>   'STRUCT' '<' in column name or primary key or foreign key

```
add jar /home/shashank/Desktop/Hadoopprac/Twitteranalysis/hive-json-serde.jar;

    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets (
      text STRING,
      entities STRUCT<
        hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
      user STRUCT<
        screen_name:STRING,
        friends_count:INT,
        followers_count:INT,
        statuses_count:INT,
        verified:BOOLEAN,
        utc_offset:INT,
        time_zone:STRING>
    ) 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
    LOCATION '/home/shashank/Desktop/Hadoopprac/tweetsfile.json';
```

Comment: hive version? sintax seems to be correct

Comment: I'm confused why hashtags is not just an array of strings

Comment: Hive version : hive-2.3.2

Comment: Because I need the hashtag text too for knowing the popularity of tweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so finally got the answer actually the issue is with the reserve keyword,the user is the reserve keyword in hive parsing so user should be put in `` and run the query thanks for effort by hlagos and cricket_007.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets (
      text STRING,
      entities STRUCT<
        hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
      `user` STRUCT<
        screen_name:STRING,
        friends_count:INT,
        followers_count:INT,
        statuses_count:INT,
        verified:BOOLEAN,
        utc_offset:INT,
        time_zone:STRING>
    ) 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
    LOCATION '/home/shashank/Desktop/Hadoopprac/tweetsfile.json';
```